# Howdo I tell which kernel modules are required?

Tags: gentoo, kernel-modules

Say, I have a default Gentoo install with all the modules (e.g. device drivers) compiled. From this point, is there an easy way to exclude the unused modules the next time I recompile the kernel?

Comment: Seeing I can't tag stuff on this site yet, please add a "gentoo" tag, otherwise you'll keep getting debian answers.

Comment: that comment you just made is why im considering a switch to *bsd

Answer (score 3):

`make localmodconfig` and `make localyesconfig` (introduced in 2.6.32, which was released in December 3, 2009) will select the modules needed to load the modules in use.

[More info](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_32#head-11f54cdac41ad6150ef817fd68597554d9d05a5f).

Note that this does not take into account modules that were loaded once, but are currently unloaded. ArchLinux has a [modprobed_db](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Modprobed_db) thing that workarounds this, I don't know whether Gentoo has one as well.

Answer (score 2):

I use the discover package in debian to figure out what kernel modules I could possibly load. Specifically:

```
apt-get install discover
discover --data-path=linux/module/name|sort|uniq
```

For my amd dual core desktop with an nvidia chipset I get:

```
amd74xx
emu10k1
emu10k1-gp
forcedeth
i2c-nforce2
ohci1394
sata_nv
```

Here's a [short essay](http://linuxgazette.net/issue88/tag/2.html) on hardware detection in linux, including some text on using discover.

Comment: I believe Gentoo is using portage, which is different from that of debian and debian variants. The command is "emerge"

Comment: Sadly, `discover` isn't in portage :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use "lsmod" to know the kernel modules

Comment: this only shows modules currently running, not really useful when trying to trim the fat

Answer (score 2):

Show drivers/modules in use:

```
lspci -v
```

Comment: `lspci -k`, will show you all of your _pci_ hardware, and which modules are being used for that hardware. `emerge sys-apps/pciutils` for lcpci.

Answer (score 1):

if we were going to get into technicalities, i would say you could just unload those modules, and then you would not need to recompile.  However, I think you meant "to include only drivers to my specific hardware".  In that case, I would suggest:

```
dmesg | less
```

look through that and see what hardware details you can extrapolate.  Then, when you go to compile the kernel, look through all the components and see if it makes a mention to your hardware.  After rebooting, check to make sure all the hardware works.

In archlinux, there is a bash script called `[hwd][1]`, i assume it would work on gentoo (perhaps a bit of hacking required), but it will tell  you about what you got under the hood.  This is my work computer:

```
[theman@work]# hwd -s
HARDWARE DETECT ver 5.5 (simple mode)
Kernel     : 2.6.29-ARCH
CPU & Cache: Processor 0: Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2200  @ 2.20GHz 2194MHz, 1024 KB Cache
Processor 1: Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2200  @ 2.20GHz 2194MHz, 1024 KB Cache

Sound(a)   : 82801G ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller module: snd-hda-intel 
Video      : GeForce 8400 GS server: Xorg (vesa)  
Driver     : xf86-video-vesa   module: - 
Monitor    : Generic Monitor  H: 28.0-96.0kHz V: 50.0-75.0Hz
Mouse      : Logitech, Inc. Marble Mouse (4-button)  xtype: IMPS2 device: /dev/input/mice
HDD        : 82801GB/GR/GH ICH7 Family SATA IDE Controller module: ata_piix 
USB        : 82801G ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 module: uhci_hcd 
USB2       : 82801G ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller module: ehci_hcd 

Ethernet   : RTL8139/8139C/8139C+ module: 8139too 
Network    : No wireless card

Menu       : Main menu: hwd
All        : Detect all hardwares: hwd -e
X sample   : Generate X sample: hwd -x
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a shellscript in "Linux Kernel in a nutshell" by GKH, which does this by approximation. The script is freely downloadable from the books website and hasn't got a copyright message, so I assume I can post it here.

```
for i in `find /sys/ -name modalias -exec cat {} \;`; do
        /sbin/modprobe --config /dev/null --show-depends $i ;
done | rev | cut -f 1 -d '/' | rev | sort -u
```

The scripts output is a list of module *your hardware* needs to function. It does *not* list modules that are needed to make certain software work, like ipv6.so!

@Greg: if you don't want this posted like this, I'll remove it ;-)

Comment: This assumes that modules for the hardware are already available, which makes it of limited use for kernel configuration. Still, that caveat about software kernel requirements is _golden_

Answer (score 1):

One some distributions there's also a nice nifty tool called *hwinfo*, which gives you lots of useful information about your hardware.

To get more to know about the kernel modules, *lspci* and *lsmod* always have done a good job for me.

Comment: In portage as sys-apps/hwinfo ; sys-apps/lshw performs similar

Answer (score 0):

If you are recompiling the kernel. The best thing to do is to know your hardware well using the method presented by [theman_on_osx](https://serverfault.com/users/4217/themanonosx). List all your components. You just have to uncheck / exclude the modules (that aren't needed) from the menu (i.e. if you are recompiling it via make menuconfig / make xconfig).

You can also unload modules that are loadable on the fly using "rmmod."

Answer (score 0):

*lspci* should also help you.